# React rendering one component but not the other

Tags: reactjs, components, tailwind-css

I've done a nice bit of coding with React but this is my first time having this issue.

NavBar is rendering as it should but the Products component will not show.

This is my first time using Tailwind so I'm not sure if it has anything to do with that? Hoping I'm just having a moment and something obvious stands out to someone!

- [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKI2R.png)
- [App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEiHB.png)
- [Homepage.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/441PL.png)
- [NavBar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLtmW.png)
- [Products.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJIf5.png)

I'm not getting any errors and I've tried moving around where I rendered Products but no matter where I render it I'm still having the same issue. I've restarted everything as well and I'm not having any issue getting changes for NavBar & App to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.